# How can I deal with duplicate values when creating a dictionary in Python?

Tags: python, list, dictionary, debugging, duplicates

I am a beginner in python, and I would like to create a simple program that assigns each element in list1 to its respective element in list2 using the zip function.

```
list1=[1,2,3,4,1]
list2=[2,3,4,5,6]
dictionary=dict(zip(list1,list2))
print(dictionary)
```

However, because I have a duplicate value in list1, the dictionary displays the following results:

```
{1: 6, 2: 3, 3: 4, 4: 5}
```

Because 1 is a duplicate value in list1, only 1:6 is displayed and not 1:2 as well. How can I change my code such that the duplicate value is taken into account and is displayed in its respective order?

`{1: 2, 2: 3, 3: 4, 4: 5, 1: 6}`

Thank you

Comment: There's no way to achieve what you're looking for. Not with a python ``dict``.

Comment: If you have duplicates in the first list, you should not do this. What are you actually trying to achieve?

Comment: How would you propose to retrieve the 1:6 value from the dictionary when you really wanted the 1:2 value instead, or vice-versa? You would not be able to, of course.

Comment: An important part of the definition of a dict is that keys are unique...

Comment: You can't do this. But you can store list of numbers as a value: `{1: [2, 6], 2: [3], 3: [4], 4: [5]}`. Do you want it?

Comment: What would happen if you called `dict.get(1)`? Would it return 2 or 6?

Answer (score 2):

What you ask is not possible with a Python `dict`, since that goes against the definition of a dict--keys must be unique. The comments explain why that is the case.

However, there are multiple other ways that may be useful to you that can achieve almost the same affect. One simple, yet not terribly useful, way is:

```
almost_dictionary = list(zip(list1, list2))
```

This gives the result

```
[(1, 2), (2, 3), (3, 4), (4, 5), (1, 6)]
```

which sometimes can be used like a dictionary. However, this probably is not what you want. Better is a `dict` or `defaultdict` that, for each key, holds a `list` of all the values connected with that key. The `defaultdict` is easier to use, though harder to set up:

```
dictionary = defaultdict(list)
for k, v in zip(list1, list2):
    dictionary[k].append(v)
print(dictionary)
```

This gives the result

```
defaultdict(<class 'list'>, {1: [2, 6], 2: [3], 3: [4], 4: [5]})
```

and you see that each key has each value--the values are just in lists. The value of `dictionary[1]` is `[2, 6]`, so you have both values to work with.

Which method you choose depends on your purpose for the dictionary.

Comment: Ok, this makes sense. Thank you.